# Running googletest with separated src- and test-folders

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

Here my minimal example (https://github.com/theCollectiv/cmake_minimal). I first got this project structure with seperate Headerplacement (-> src and include)

```
.
├── 1Cmake.sh
├── 2runExe.sh
├── 3cleanTarget.sh
├── 4runTest.sh
├── 7VersionOfCurrentTools.sh
├── build
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├──...
│   ...
├── CMakeDefaults.txt
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── compile_commands.json -> ...
├── data
├── docs
│   ├── ...
├── include
│   └── addition
│       └── addition.hpp
├── src
│   ├── addition
│   │   └── addition.cpp
│   ├── main.cpp
├── tests
│   └── test01_proofOfWork
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       └── tests.cpp
```

main.cpp

```
#include "addition.hpp"

#include <iostream>
int main() {
  int a = 5;
  int b = 3;
  std::cout << "a is " << a << "\nb is " << b << "\nThe Sum of both "
<< add(a, b) << std::endl; }
```

addition.cpp

```
#include "addition.hpp"
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

header of addition.cpp: addition.hpp

```
#pragma once
int add(int a, int b);
```

The CMakeList.txt in the root-folder looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21.2)
set (This
    Project_main)

project(${This}
    LANGUAGES CXX
    VERSION 1.000)

enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(./tests/test01_proofOfWork)

# Custom Variables
set(QUELLE src/main.cpp)
set(ZIEL finalExecutable)

# integrate lib (with .cpp and its header)
set(LIB_1 addition)

add_library(                                
    ${LIB_1}                                
    STATIC src/addition/addition.cpp        
    )
# add .hpp hinzufuegen and connect to lib
target_include_directories(              
    ${LIB_1}                             
    PUBLIC include/addition             
    )
# add executable
add_executable(${ZIEL} ${QUELLE})       

# linking the lib  
target_link_libraries(                  
    ${ZIEL}                             
    PRIVATE ${LIB_1}                    
    #    PUBLIC ${LIB_1}                    
    )
```

Now I want to add unit tests by using googletest. I'm using ubuntu and googletest is installed in my systempath (with shared libs) and working.

**I'm now a little bit stuck, getting googletest well integrated in the project.**

The CMakeList.txt in the tests-dir:

```
# Name of the Tests
set (This
    runTest)

# Location of the test
set (Sources
    tests.cpp)

# executable of the test
add_executable(${This} ${Sources})

# linking libs for the test
target_link_libraries(${This} PUBLIC
    GTest::gmock
    GTest::gtest
    GTest::gmock_main
    GTest::gtest_main)
# registrating the test 
gtest_discover_tests(${This})
```

The test.cpp

```
// tests.cpp
// #include "./../../include/addition/addition.hpp"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h>

// bool foo(){
//     return true;
// }
// 
// 
// TEST(Simpletest, trueEqualsTrue) {
//     EXPECT_TRUE(foo());
//     EXPECT_FALSE(foo());
//     EXPECT_EQ(true, foo());
//     ASSERT_FALSE(foo());
//     EXPECT_EQ(false, foo());
// }
//
TEST(SquareRootTest, PositiveNos) {
    ASSERT_EQ(18.0, add(1,17));
    EXPECT_EQ(6, add(1,6));
    ASSERT_EQ(25.4, add(55, -1));
    ASSERT_EQ(0, add(-4, 4));
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

The de-commented test code works and compiles fine, so gtest works fine (means: if I m testing code, thats in the same file the code is tested).

But... (I'm new to this stuff, so maybe its an easy (or noob) question):
The reason, why I added the googletest is to test the code in the src- or -include dir. Therefore I got the add all the headers and files in the these dirs for test cases all the time.
Is there a good way to make all of them available for the possible tests that I might run without configuring it all the time?

---

My problem is,

1. that the de-commented code works/compiles fine (of code in the same location like the test is). That means:

   - googletest is installed correctly
   - the tests-CMakeLists.txt is working correctly (and the root-CmakeLists.txt too)
2. If I want to compile the test-code, that is not de-commented (that means the 'code to test' is not in the same file like the test itself), it is complaining for missing headers. If I add them, the compilation of the tests quits with errors (like "cmake line XXX" ...doesnt tell me anything or "undefined reference too"). The problem I got

   - it doesnt compile the tests (obvious)
   - even if it would compile, I got to rebuild all the things (adding headers in the test-source-code) in the test-directory like I did in the root-directory (similar/same file linking in both of them). If I got a more complex project structure (using a function in a file which uses functions from another file), this is 'doing the same exact same stuff in for the normal project (src and include) and in the tests-dir'. Or am I wrong at this point?

---

Solution:

```
# linking libs for the test
target_link_libraries(${This} PUBLIC
    GTest::gmock
    GTest::gtest
    GTest::gmock_main
    GTest::gtest_main
    # Solution: Got to link the lib(s) (which I want to test in the root-dir) against the test-executable
    addition
    )
```

Comment: `I'm now a little bit stuck` With what exactly? `Is there a good way` How to measure "good"? Is there something not working with your current setup?

Comment: Thx for the comment and feedback. I extended my question (last paragraph) to be more precise. If there is something more still unclear, let me know plz.
PS.: Code for this example https://github.com/theCollectiv/cmake_minimal

Comment: You're not linking against your project libraries in tests/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: `ike "cmake line XXX" ...doesnt tell me anything or "undefined reference too"` it doesn't tell you - but it will tell others. Please post the exact verbatim verbose error messages, at best from `cmake --build <builddir> --verbose` and `ctest -VV`. Shouldn't you want to `#include <addition.hpp>`?

Comment: @Stephan: Do I always have to link against the project-libraries again in the tests-CMakeLists.txt again? ...if the project gets bigger, its really hard to keep it analog/according to the project structure for every small change in the root-CMakeList.txt.

Comment: @KamilCuk ...no, I did that #include <addition.hpp> doesn't work, because the sub-CMakeList.txt doesn't know it. The relative path doesnt work either. Its a scope-thing, I guess. I will post the error messages ...first I will give it a try to link the libs like Stephan wrote.

Comment: `Do I always have to link against the project-libraries again in the tests-CMakeLists.txt again?` Not again, once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not linking yout test project against your library. So it doesn't use your library. Link it.

```
target_link_libraries(${This} addition)
```

Comment: Thank you, now its working like expected -> so I can test against 'addition'.

If I add a new lib in the root-project, do I always have to edit the both CMakeLists.txt's? There is no way around it, or?

Comment: I do not understand. If you add a new library _and you want to use it_ in some executable, then you have to link with it. I believe that's pretty straightforward.